# radio button in gridview always returns checked = false inside ajax updatepanel

Tags: ajax, gridview, radio-button, updatepanel

I am using UpdatePanel and Ajax Tabcontainer. I have one item template column which has both checkbox and radiobutton. Either one of them is visible at a time based on one bit kind of field.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvAutoMatchFund" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ClientIDMode="Static"
    AllowPaging="True" PageSize="50" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None"
    OnRowDataBound="gvAutoMatchFund_RowDataBound" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3"
    onpageindexchanging="gvAutoMatchFund_PageIndexChanging" 
    Width="100%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DYNAMO_FUNDNAME" HeaderText="Dynamo Fund Name" ItemStyle-Width="25%" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DYNAMO_FUNDID" HeaderText="Dynamo Fund ID" ItemStyle-Width="25%" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="INVESTRAN_FUNDNAME" HeaderText="Investran Fund Name" ItemStyle-Width="25%" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="INVESTRAN_SYSTEMFUNDID" HeaderText="Inv. Sys. Fund ID" />
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="80px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelAll" Text="Select" runat="server"  />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSel" runat="server" Visible='<%#(!(bool)Eval("ISMULTIPLE"))%>' />
                <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoSel" runat="server" Visible='<%#((bool)Eval("ISMULTIPLE"))%>' />                                                                    
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#C6E5F5" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#4695BD" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
    <EmptyDataRowStyle ForeColor="Maroon" />
</asp:GridView>
```

I am populating it after checking postback

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
 {
    ...
    PopulateMyGV();
 }
```

When a button is clicked I am trying to loop thru each item in this gridview and using FindControl method to find checkbox and radiobutton. Upto this point is works however radiobutton checked is always false even if it is selected. However checkbox works fine(gives correct value for checked property) if selected or not. See code below

In button click

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvAutoMatchFund.Rows)
{   

    CheckBox chkSel = (CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("chkSel");      
    RadioButton rdoSel = (RadioButton)gvr.FindControl("rdoSel");

    if (chkSel != null)
    {
        if (chkSel.Checked)
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    if (rdoSel != null)
    {
        if (rdoSel.Checked)
        {
            ...
        }
    }

}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: More onto this same question, what we found is another weird thing that radio selection works in second attempts means if we try for even number button click it does return correct value for checked!!! extremely difficult as that means logic is correct then what's wrong please help.

Answer (score 0):

After spending lot of hours, finally we found that this strange behavior occurs because we were changing the ID of radio button programmatically in RowDataBound event. See the code below.

```
    protected void gvAutoMatchFund_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            USP_MDM_SUGGESTED_AUTOMATCH_FUNDResult objUSP_MDM_SUGGESTED_AUTOMATCH_FUNDResult = (USP_MDM_SUGGESTED_AUTOMATCH_FUNDResult)e.Row.DataItem;

            RadioButton rdoSel = (RadioButton)e.Row.FindControl("rdoSel");
            rdoSel.ID = "rdoSel_" + objUSP_MDM_SUGGESTED_AUTOMATCH_FUNDResult.DYNAMO_FUNDID
                        + "_" + objUSP_MDM_SUGGESTED_AUTOMATCH_FUNDResult.INVESTRAN_SYSTEMFUNDID
                        + "_" + objUSP_MDM_SUGGESTED_AUTOMATCH_FUNDResult.INVESTRAN_FUNDID;         

        }
    }
```

So I removed above logic and used following logic instead to pass various parameters along with radiobutton

```
    protected void gvAutoMatchFund_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            USP_MDM_SUGGESTED_AUTOMATCH_FUNDResult objUSP_MDM_SUGGESTED_AUTOMATCH_FUNDResult = (USP_MDM_SUGGESTED_AUTOMATCH_FUNDResult)e.Row.DataItem;

            RadioButton rdoSel = (RadioButton)e.Row.FindControl("rdoSel");
            string sValue = "rdoSel_" + objUSP_MDM_SUGGESTED_AUTOMATCH_FUNDResult.DYNAMO_FUNDID
                        + "_" + objUSP_MDM_SUGGESTED_AUTOMATCH_FUNDResult.INVESTRAN_SYSTEMFUNDID
                        + "_" + objUSP_MDM_SUGGESTED_AUTOMATCH_FUNDResult.INVESTRAN_FUNDID;

            rdoSel.Attributes.Add("value", sValue);     

        }
    }
```

That solved the both issues I described above.